# Postgres select query acquired AccessShareLock and blocked other running queries

Tags: postgresql

ideally, Queries wait only for ExclusiveLock on a table but we saw a weird behaviour in our prod infra.  select queries were waiting for accessShareLock on a view in postgres, any reason why it can be possible? Here is the output of lock monitoring query, pg_locks table of postgres

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xt0sfYicrDiPEdd3QdVVEm--cdHI3QGHSKb2jP2ofjI/edit#gid=1512744594

Comment: Please include relevant information as part of the question ([formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)) - don't link to some external site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only lock that conflicts with an `AccessShareLock` is an `AccessExclusiveLock`, which is tanken by statements like `TRUNCATE`, `DROP TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`. So either one of these statements is currently running or is waiting for a transaction to finish (locks are queued).

Avoid long database transactions, and the problem will go away.

Comment: We have found the issue, issue was with a GIN index which was taking lot of time, Thanks for your answer.